# View .hdr in GenBin Format

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I'm using GDAL. I have created a .HDR and .BIL file from a .TIF but I want to have .HDR file in format as it displays in GenBin not like default or EHdr or ENVI format.

My desired output:

```
{{{
BANDS:      1
ROWS:    6542
COLS:    9340
...
}}}
```

but the output I'm getting is like:

```
BYTEORDER      I
LAYOUT         BIL
NROWS          4096
NCOLS          4096
NBANDS         1
NBITS          16
BANDROWBYTES   8192
TOTALROWBYTES  8192
PIXELTYPE      UNSIGNEDINT
```

Comment: The GenBin driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/genbin.html#raster-genbin is read-only. You must create GenBin formatted headers by some other means.

Comment: How ? I want to convert a .TIF file to .BIN with a .HDR file using gdal

Comment: With some scripting or programming language like Python or maybe even with Excel. The corresponding lines do not seem to be hard to find. I fear that GDAL does not offer that kind of utility for manipulating text files.

Comment: @user30184 do you know where one might find the possible header keys? The documentation page you linked just says "The .hdr files supported by this driver are look something like this" and lists 3 possible keys to include

Comment: The keys supported by GDAL can be found the sources. Find rows that contain `CSLFetchNameValue` in file https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/frmts/raw/genbindataset.cpp